# Smooth coverings are open maps proof verification

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M,N$ be connected, smooth manifolds. A function $F:M \rightarrow N$ is a local diffeomorphism if for all $p \in M$ there exists open $U \subseteq M$ with $p \in U$ such that $F(U) \subseteq N$ is open and $F: U \rightarrow F(U)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Additionally, a function $\pi: N \rightarrow M$ is a smooth covering map if $\pi$ is surjective, smooth and for every $p \in M$ there exists open $U \subseteq M$ with $p \in U$ such that for each component $U'$ of $\pi^{-1}(U)$, $\pi: U' \rightarrow U$ is a diffeomorphism.

An exercise in Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" then asks to prove that a smooth covering is a local diffeomorphism and an open map. I proved the first part of this, it was fairly straightforward. I just need some verification of the second part.

(To prove a smooth covering $\pi: N \rightarrow M$ is an open map):

Let $V \subseteq N$ be open. Since $\pi$ is a local diffeomorphism, for each $p \in V$ there exists open $U_p \subseteq N$ with $p \in U_p$ such that $\pi(U_p) \subseteq M$ is open and $\pi: U_p \rightarrow \pi(U_p)$ is a diffeomorphism. Since $V, U_p$ are open, $V \cap U_p$ is open. Then $\pi(V \cap U_p)$ is open, since $V \cap U_p \subseteq U_p$ and $\pi: U_p \rightarrow \pi(U_p)$ is a diffeomorphism (and thus homeomorphism). We then have $\pi(V)= \cup_{p \in V}  \pi(V \cap U_p)$, which is a union of open sets and hence is open. $\Box$

Does this look ok?

Comment: Your argument looks fine. You might also look at Proposition 4.6 (in the second edition).

Comment: But your definition of a smooth covering map is not right. Look again.

Comment: Thanks, I believe I fixed it. I also added the hypothesis that $M,N$ are connected, since I believe this is actually needed here if we follow Lee's definition.

Comment: The definition is still not quite right.

Comment: Component of $\pi^{-1}(U)$, not $U$. Fixed it.

Comment: That's it. Good.